# Why AWS Lambda is slow when calling EC2 service from it?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I am using trial version of AWS instance and have free EC2 server of 1GB RAM.

I have Mongo DB installed in EC2 and written one simple AWS Lambda function in Java(tried in Node js too). Both are in same region.

When I am trying to save one simple JSON in DB of EC2 byLambda function, its taking too long time around 30 seconds and then getting time out.

I also tried to put a message in Kafka queue which is installed on simillar kind of EC2 server using Lambda function, its taking almost a minute to put that message in Kafka queue.

Why this is sooooooo slow? Am I missing something or shall we blame the 1GB Ubuntu/Linux EC2 server? Or something fishy about AWS Lambda? Tried with both Java and Node JS?

Comment: You probably have not opened required ports in the security group.

Comment: Where should I get this information?

Comment: Thanks. I got what do you mean. I update port in security group and it's working like a charm now. thanks!!!

Comment: How is your problem solved? @hjpotter92 I have kafka intalled in on ec2 instance and I'm sending a message from producer code in lambda and it's giving me error broker not found. However, from outside for the same request it's working fine. Could you please help me in this?

Comment: You should update/create Security group in EC2 console and provide Kafka port in port range. Adding screenshot of same in my answer below. Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked when I create Security group in EC2 console for my DB and provide DB port in port range. Check attached image.[image]